# Событие на select после загрузки ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

При загрузке контента через AJAX не действует JS события!
Что нужно сделать?

```js
$("#target").change(function() {
  var gord_top_sd = $(this).val();
  $('.ikon_gorser').show();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/handler/gorod_php.php", // Обработчик.
    data: "city=" + gord_top_sd,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response) {
      $('.target_gor').html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="target" class="ui search dropdown" name="region">

  <option value="">Поиск</option>
  <?php foreach ($city as $region=>$cityList) { 
      echo '<option class=" oblast" value="' . $region . '">' . $region . '</option>' . "\n"; 
  } ?>

</select>

<div class="target_gor">
  <div class="ikon_gorser">
    <div class="ui active centered inline loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно добавить код в вопрос, чтобы было видно в чем проблема. Но можно предположить что 1) события нужно делегировать, например с помощью метода `on` в jQuery, либо явно навешивать их снова после добавления в дом

Comment: и разметку Html

Comment: не надо добавлять сниппет, который не работает, добавляйте просто как блок кода

Comment: и где хоть одно событие которое теряется?

Comment: Дело в том что обработчик AJAX загружает контент в класс target_gor но JS  к нему не применяется!

Comment: какой из добавленных в вопрос js должен был применяться к загруженному Html?

Comment: Я использую вот этот фреймворк http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html посмотрите какие там  select (С плавной анимацией и поиском по нему)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).